# Does a logical right shift always clip the source to 32-bit before shifting it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bit-shift

Simple, really. Is `0xf12345678>>>4` always supposed to produce `0x1234567` as a result in JavaScript? Can I assume this would work in all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to the ECMAScript 5 specification, the `>>>` operator performs the internal `ToUInt32` algorithm.

See [Section 11.7.3 of the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x11.7.3):

> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
> 4. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 5. Let lnum be ToUint32(lval).
> 6. Let rnum be ToUint32(rval).
> 7. Let shiftCount be the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits of rnum, that is, compute rnum & 0x1F.
> 8. Return the result of performing a zero-filling right shift of lnum by shiftCount bits. Vacated bits are filled with zero. The result is
>      an unsigned 32-bit integer.

It is spelled out very clearly that the result is a 32-bit integer, always.

The `>>>` operator is used commonly to convert to a 32-bit unsigned integer. For instance, MDN uses it in their shims. Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Should be a reliable assumption. Any JS interpreter will read the `0xf12345678` as a single operand before it computes any operations. If you want to be safe, why not `(0xf12345678)>>>4`?

Some details on the issue here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

> Bitwise operators treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits (zeros
>   and ones), rather than as decimal, hexadecimal, or octal numbers. For
>   example, the decimal number nine has a binary representation of 1001.
>   Bitwise operators perform their operations on such binary
>   representations, but they return standard JavaScript numerical values.